# WPF ComboBox Dropdown Not Displaying

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am having a problem getting the WPF combobox to display the drop down portion. The combobox renders but when I click the down arrow the values in the combobox don't display. I can use the arrows to navigate between the different values.

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <ComboBox Text="Is not open" Margin="14,14,0,0" Height="20" Width="150" IsEditable="True" IsEnabled="True">
        <ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: I just copied and pasted this into a new project and it's behaving as expected.  What is your surrounding XAML?

Comment: As Josh said, what is the rest of the XAML. Are you doing any styling/templating on ComboBox or ComboBoxItem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are likely applying a style to ComboBoxes which is altering the ListBox part of the ComboBox control.  Expression Blend is helpful if you are editing the ControlTemplate for the ComboBox.  Let us know if you need help with a ComboBox ControlTemplate.